# How to protect a diamond ring so the stones don't fall out when it takes a knock

Tags: jewelry

In the past I loved this silver ring I purchased in india, with a square top part and clustered with around 25 tiny diamonds. Unfortunately the odd diamond fell out after the ring took some knocks and I fell out of love with it.

So my g/f recently bought me a similar type of ring.

Looks like this
[image: Looks Like This]

What I would like to ask is if it a good idea to paint clear nail varnish over the ring to stop the stones falling out?

Its Silver although the photo is of a gold one.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Covering a cut stone with something like clear nail polish will diminish the shine of the stones. And you have to expect the polish to break or flake of at some point.

Instead you should go to a professional jeweller and explain the problem to them. They can have a look at the tiny metal protrusions that hold the stones in place and reshape some of them if needed. Or they can glue the stones in place (on the backside) with a professional glue that doesn't break off.